# How can I open edumips.jar?

Tags: jar, edumips64

I want to run edumips.jar. Whenever I try to open, Java control panel is opened.

When I execute:

[image]
strong text

It is first time to download java and excecute .jar file.

What I want:

[image]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: there is now an MSI installer for EduMIPS64 which allows you to install and run the simulator without worrying about installing a JRE and configuring it: https://github.com/EduMIPS64/edumips64/releases/download/v1.2.8/EduMIPS64-1.2.8.msi (version 1.2.8 was released at the time of updating this answer, there might be more recent ones).

You need to make sure the Java runtime is associated with the `.jar` extension to open it with double-click.

To open it once, try right-clicking on the JAR file select `Open With...` and find the Java runtime binary (it's "OpenJDK Platform Binary" on my Windows machine).

You may also be able to fix this by re-installing the Java Runtime (JRE): usually installers associate `.jar` files to the Java binary automatically.

Worst case, if Java is installed and the `PATH` is set up correctly, you can run it from the command line by using the command `java -jar edumips64-1.2.6-standalone.jar`.

To open the command line, press `Win+x` and choose `Windows PowerShell`. Your JAR might be in the `Downloads` directory so try `java -jar Downloads\edumips64-1.2.6-standalone.jar`.